# Datagrid Colors

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I make my own style for datagrid, I had changed every thing but there's a small part of datagrid make me crazy, because I can't change color for this part. I don't know the name of this part, as showing in the image :

[image]
[image]

How can I change color it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear from your image, but if that part is part of the `ScrollBar` then you can add a `Style` *without defining an `x:Key` for it* into your `DataGrid.Resources` section. That way, it can be implicitly applied to the `ScrollBar` parts. You can start with the default `Style` and then adjust it for your needs. You can find the default `Style` in the [ScrollBar Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. There is quite a lot of it so you'll have to do some experimentation with it.

UPDATE >>>

If you are talking about the `Button`s that you can click to select the row, I believe that that part is called the row header. You can add a `Style` for that using the `RowHeaderStyle` property. Please see the [WPF override DataGrid RowHeader template and manage to select rows still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542913/wpf-override-datagrid-rowheader-template-and-manage-to-select-rows-still) post for help with that.

Alternatively, I believe that you can hide it altogether by setting the `DataGrid.RowHeaderWidth` property to `0`.

Comment: I updating the question, what I mean the yellow part.